# Bogus filename in SVN

Tags: svn

I am working on SVN, and trying to commit some of the changes I made. But I got an error message telling me that

```
delete --force C:/workspace/Project/src/main/java/com/test/ml
    Bogus filename
svn: 'C:\workspace\Project\src\main\java\com\test\ml' does not exist
```

does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Why would you use forward slashes in a local path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion does not generally support absolute pathnames in operations such as delete. What happens when you try a relative pathname? For example, if you're in the `C:\workspace\project` directory,

```
svn delete src/main/java/com/test/ml
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolve this by creating a new C:\workspace\Project\src\main\java\com\test\ml, then marking it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If Greg's answer isn't the issue, you might want to double-check your capitalization; if you're working with others who are using a *nix system, the case-insensitive nature of Windows can cause weird behaviour.  (Such as if a file rename changes only case.)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by following these 6 steps (Incase its helpful to someone):

```
1) Copy the folder in which the conflict arose to your system from eclipse.

2) Delete the folder in eclipse by right clicking, after deletion red cross will be marked.

3) Update the deleted folder via **Replace With -> Latest from Repository**

4) Commit the code, at this point it should commit.

5) Copy the contents that you saved in your local system in that folder by accepting any duplicates that follow.

6) Commit the code again and hopefully you are done without any file loss.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use tortoiseSVN - I found committing the changes from tortoise worked for me.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked, which had nothing to do with TortoiseSVN.